# Getting segmentation fault when trying to load a file in C

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I cannot figure out why I am getting a segmentation fault error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
AddressBookList * commandLoad(char * fileName)
{
AddressBookList * list;
AddressBookNode * node;

char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
char *ptr;
int id;
char *name;

FILE * fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
printf(">Opening the file %s.\n", fileName);
if(fp == NULL){
    printf(">Error: Unable to find the specified file. ");
    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}
else{
    printf(">Loading the file ...\n");
    list = createAddressBookList();
    while(fgets(line,MAX_LINE_LENGTH,fp) != NULL){
        if(line[0]!= '#'){
            id = (int)strtol(strtok(line,", "), &ptr, 0);
            name = strtok(NULL,",\n");
            node = createAddressBookNode(id,name);
            if(list->size == 0){
                list->head = node;
                list->current = list->head;
                node->nextNode = NULL;
                node->previousNode = NULL;
            }
            else{
                node->previousNode = list->tail;
                node->previousNode->nextNode = node;
            }
            list->tail = node;
            list->size++;
            printf("%d,%s\n",node->id,node->name);
        }
    }
    printf(">%d phone book entries have been loaded from the file.\n",list->size);
    printf(">Closing the file.\n");
}
fclose(fp);
return list;
```

}

```
AddressBookList * createAddressBookList()
{
   AddressBookList * list = malloc(sizeof(AddressBookList));
   return list;
}
```

I am passing the argv from main to commandLoad and trying to load the file in this function. Below is the function along with the function for createAddressBookList in case I am missing something there as well. The function createAddressBookNode wasn't included because it works the same as list.

Comment: 1. Use a debugger. 2. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` doesn't initialize memory. The initial values of `list` are garbage.

Also, check your call to `strtok`; the `delim` parameter looks suspicious. I can't imagine how its making this crash but it will be troublesome if you don't fix it.